How to configure keyboard shortcuts in Midnight Commander (Windows) to open files in different editors?
I want to set up keyboard shortcuts in Midnight Commander (running mc.exe in Windows cmd) to:

Open the current directory in Visual Studio Code
Open the current file in Vim
Open the current file in Emacs
Open .sln files in Visual Studio's devenv.exe

What changes do I need to make to MC's configuration files mc.keymap/mc.ext to achieve this? I'm specifically looking for:

Where to place the configuration files on Windows
The correct syntax for the key bindings
The correct command syntax for Windows cmd batch (not bash)


Where did you get MC for winders? ... It's probably %Appdata%/Local or %Appdata%/Roaming or %Userprofile%/.config  . If you paste your question into perplexity (llm), it may have some advice :)

@ЯрославРахматуллин thanks for the comment. I checked the F9 > Options > Save setup and realised things are saved to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Midnight Commander\ini. But I have no idea what the syntax should be achive the above keyboard shortcuts.

you may follow-up on this issue here.
